Strategy to roll a 10-sided die

Suppose we play a game with a 10-sided die where we roll and sum our rolls. We can stop any time, and the
sum is our score. However, if our sum is ever a multiple of 10, our score is zero, and our game is over.
What strategy will yield the greatest expected score? What is the expected score with this strategy?

My approach:
Possible outcomes of the die: {$1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10$}
Let's generalize this with the following equation:
$$km < n < (k+1)m$$
Where, $n$ is our current score, $m$ is the multiple we're trying to avoid, $k$ is some integer greater than $0$.
For $n = 11$, $m = 10$, and $k = 1$
$$10 < 11 < 20$$
For a 10-sided die, we shouldn't reroll if our variables satisfy the following condition:
$$(k+1)m - 10 < n < (k+2)m$$
for example, if $k = 1$,
$$10 < n < 30$$
If our current score is between $(k+1)m - 10$ and $(k+2)m$, the best case expected score if we reroll is less than $\frac{9}{10}(k+2)m - 1$. Since, with $\frac{1}{10}$ chance we hit a multiple of $m$.
Now we need to find for what value of $k$ will the current score be greater than the expected score. This will be our stopping condition.
$$(k+1)m - 10 > \frac{9}{10}(k+2)m - 1$$
$$ k > 8 + \frac{91}{m}$$
For $m = 10$,
$$ k > 17.1 $$
Therefore, we must stop rerolling when $k = 18$. Stopping condition:
$$180 < n < 190$$
We keep rerolling and stop when our score is between $180$ and $190$.
With this strategy, I found the expected score by simulating with ChatGPT to be $5.91$.
Is my approach correct?
Code:
import random

# Simulation parameters
m = 10  # Value of m (multiple to avoid)
stop_threshold = 180  # Stopping threshold for the strategy
num_simulations = 100000  # Number of simulations

# Function to simulate the game with the given strategy
def simulate_game(m, stop_threshold):
    total_score = 0
    for _ in range(num_simulations):
        score = 0
        while True:
            roll = random.randint(1, 10)  # Roll a 10-sided die
            score += roll
            if score % m == 0:  # Game ends with a score of 0 if multiple of m
                score = 0
                break
            if score >= stop_threshold:  # Stop rolling based on strategy
                break
        total_score += score
    return total_score / num_simulations  # Return the average score

# Simulate and find the expected score
expected_score = simulate_game(m, stop_threshold)
expected_score


It's problem number 78 here: https://www.madandmoonly.com/doctormatt/mathematics/dice1.pdf and solution is also given.

@ploosu2 - is that for $6$-sided dice?

@Henry Oh, right.

@ploosu2 Yes. But I wanted to try this variation of the game and see if my approach is right.

Your "Stopping condition: our score is between $180$ and $190$" looks far too high which may be why your simulated expected score at the start of $5.91$ looks too low.

Since you have a simulation, you can test the correctness of your stopping condition by trying other stopping conditions, for example, $170$ or $190$. If you do that, you will find that $180$ is not optimal. (At least, when I ran the simulation with different conditions, that's what I found.)

Addendum-1 added to quasi-rebel against the rise of the computers.

Addendum added to respond to the comment-question of F.U.A.S.

Alternative approach - specific to this game.
The decision must be based on your current score.
Assume that your current score is
$~10a + b~: ~a \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}, ~b \in \{1,2,\cdots,9\}.~$
So, assuming that you roll, $~\dfrac{1}{10}$-th of the time, you lose $~(10a + b).$
Because your current score is $~10a + b,~$ the bad roll is specifically $~10 - b.~$
On the plus side, $~\dfrac{9}{10}$-th of the time, you will roll some element in $~\{1,2,\cdots,10\},~$ other than $~(10 - b).~$
When this happens, the average value that you will roll is
$$\frac{55 - (10 - b)}{9} = \frac{45 + b}{9}.$$
So, your overall expectation is
$$\left[ ~\frac{9}{10} \times \frac{45+b}{9} ~\right] - \left[ ~\frac{1}{10} \times (10a + b) ~\right]$$
$$= \frac{45 + b}{10} - \frac{10a + b}{10} = \frac{45 - 10a}{10}.$$
So, you should roll if and only if $~a \leq 4.$  That is, roll if and only if your current winnings are $~\leq 49.$
The (somewhat) counter-intuitive result that the strategy is independent of $~b~$ is explained by reasoning that as $~b~$ increases:

The amount that you stand to lose increases.

Simultaneously, the size of the losing roll, $~(10-b),~$ which must be excluded from potential winnings, decreases.





$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
F.U.A.S. left a comment question, which I interpret to be:

Assuming that the strategy indicated in the first part of my answer is followed, what is the expected winnings.

As indicated by the comment of ploosu2 and the answer of Henry, this entire problem, including the question of expected winnings assuming optimal play, is represented by problem 78 of Mathew Conroy's A Collection of Dice Problems.
On the one hand, I am a retired professional programmer. On the other hand, I have virtually no formal training in probability theory.  So, I have to work this out intuitively.
I reviewed Conroy's solution to problem 78, including his approach to computing the expected winnings, and I see no alternative more elegant approach.  So, the best that I can do is summarize his approach, as it pertains to this particular problem, and then discuss (where appropriate) pseudo-code that may be implemented to obtain the corresponding computer assistance.
You are going to continue to roll until the sum is either an element in $~\{10,20,30,40,50\},~$ or the sum is an element in $~\{51,52,\cdots,59\}.$

Let $~E(x)~$ denote the expected winnings, if the score, at any given point is exactly $~x.$  Here, it is assumed that

$x \leq 59.$

For $~51 \leq x \leq 59, ~E(x) = x.$

$0 = E(10) = E(20) = E(30) = E(40)  = E(50).$


Conroy's approach is to work backwards from $~x = 49,~$ recursively computing $~E(48), E(47), \cdots.$  So, the final answer is then $~E(0).$  I see no way of improving on this approach.

$E(49) = \dfrac{E(50) + E(51) + \cdots + E(59)}{10}.$

$E(48) = \dfrac{E(49) + E(50) + E(51) + \cdots + E(58)}{10}.$

$E(47) = \dfrac{E(48) + E(49) + \cdots + E(57)}{10}.$

$\cdots$

$E(41) = \dfrac{E(42) + E(43) + \cdots + E(51)}{10}.$

$E(40) = 0.$

$E(39) = \dfrac{E(40) + E(41) + \cdots + E(49)}{10}.$

$\cdots$

$E(0) = \dfrac{E(1) + E(2) + \cdots + E(10)}{10}.$



So, since I can not improve on the analysis represented by the above bullet points, the problem is reduced to providing the pseudo-code to be implemented:

For $~x \in \{51,\cdots,59\}, ~E(x) = x.$

For $~x \in \{10,20,30,40,50\}, ~E(x) = 0.$

In a loop, let $~x~$ go from $~x = 49,~$ to $~x = 0,~$ decrementing $~x~$ by $~1,~$ and skipping each value of $~x~$ in $~\{10,20,30,40\}.~$

For non-skipped values of $~x,~$ apply the formula 
$E(x) = \dfrac{E(x+1) + E(x+2) + \cdots + E(x+10)}{10}.$

Do not attempt to work in rational numbers, where fractions are computed as $~\dfrac{P}{Q} ~: ~P,Q \in \Bbb{Z}.$ 
Instead, work in floating point numbers, where you carry somewhere between 10-20 decimal places for each computation.

Then, the final answer will be $~E(0).$


Presumably, this approach will merely repeat what has already been documented in the answer of Henry.  So, I similarly expect that $~E(0) \approx 19.5.$



$\underline{\text{Addendum-1}}$
Assume, from the previous section, that the expected winnings is approximately $~19.5.$  To what extent, can this computation be reverse-engineer-guesstimated?
There are two questions to be considered:

Regarding $~10,20,30,40,50~$ as land mines, what is the probability of avoiding these land mines?

Regarding $~51,52,\cdots,59,~$ as the success-range, assuming that you do make it to this success-range, what is the expected value within this success-range that you will achieve?


Reverse-engineering, I notice that

$0.9^9 \approx 0.387, ~0.9^{10} \approx 0.348.$

$\dfrac{19.5}{54} \approx 0.361, ~\dfrac{19.5}{53} \approx 0.368.$


At this point, it is time to trip the light fantastic.
If you assume that you generally have $~2~$ chances to hit a land mine, and then either hit it, or bypass it, then the $~0.9^{10}~$ computation makes sense.  So, one might surmise, from the above bullet points, that the assumption of $~2~$ chances is moderately pessimistic.
That is, one might guess that you generally have between $~1.8~$ and $~2~$ chances to hit a specific land mine.
The success range can be reached from any point 41 through 49 inclusive.  On the one hand, you could reason that you will (for example) reach 51 much more often than 59, since you only have one chance to reach 59 (from 49), and you have 10 chances to reach 51.
On the other hand, it seems that the above consideration is somewhat offset by the fact that these chances are not equally likely.  That is, assuming that you do reach the success range, I would guess that you are more likely to have reached the success range from 46 than from 41.
So, you might reasonably guesstimate that your expected winnings, assuming that you reach the success range, will be somewhat less than $~\dfrac{51 + 52 + \cdots + 59}{9}.$

This is an elegant solution for the first part, however is there one for determining the actual score? Or does it just come down to simulation or maybe dynamic programming down from 59?

@F.U.A.S. It just hit me.  Are you asking what the expected winnings will be, assuming that the strategy that I suggest is followed?  Assuming so, this is an interesting question.  I will add an Addendum where I try to tackle it.

that is exactly what I am asking. Henry's code uses dynamic programming running down from the stop roll scores and my code confirms his number of roughly 19.5 It would be nice to have a more elegant proof for this, but I don't see it and I honestly doubt it exist, so surprise me :)

@F.U.A.S. See the Addendum that I have just added to the end of my answer.  It is very easy to write your own program to compute the expected winnings.  Alas and alack, I see no alternative to writing a recursive program that decrements $~x~$ by $~1,~$ from $~x = 39,~$ to $~x = 0.~$

@F.U.A.S. See also my Addendum-1, where I rebel against the computer.

I appreciate the rebellious attitude, but I am afraid you are using the wrong numbers. Since you will keep rolling until you hit numbers larger than $49$, $E(x)=x$ is true for $x$ in between $51$ and $59$. This somewhat undermines your "guesstimation" part in addendum-1 even though the idea of having 10 chances to fail on average might be helpful. After all $0.9^{10}\cdot 55=19.177...$ I must admit I used a computer to calculate that though. ;)

Also, I am afraid the addenda take away from the elegance and brevity of the original argument, as flattered as I am by the extensive answer to my question.

@F.U.A.S. Unclear if you missed the point.  I see no elegance in my Addendum, which computes the expected profit.  However, the Addendum-1, while it does trip the light fantastic, provides alternate analysis, that (perhaps) can be fine tuned to make the Addendum obsolete.  Both the Addendum and Addendum-1 focus on expected profit, while the elegant portion of my answer does not.

@F.U.A.S. I agree that my Addendum and Addenum-1 used the wrong numbers.  I have edited the answer accordingly.

Not adding much to the great answers, but I think it's worth to notice that semi qualitative reasonings here get you very close to the correct values.
For the stopping point, you can consider that, every time you roll a dice, you on average gain $5.5$ points if you survive. Since surviving is 9 times more likely than hitting a zero, it's convenient to toss as long as your score is less than $5.5 \times 9 = 49.5$.
For the value of the game, consider that you are rolling until you hit a zero or your score is greater than $49$. So there are basically two outcomes: either you win zero or win on average something like $55$, i.e. the average between 51 and 59. If you win, you will need on average about 10 dice tosses to get there while you never hit a zero. So your value is approximately:
$$
E \simeq 55 \times \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{10} \simeq 19.2 \, .
$$
As you can see, those values are pretty close to the correct ones.

The fact that the first argument gives you the exact number 49 as a threshold to stop baffles me.

Your "Stopping condition: our score is between $180$ and $190$" looks far too high as, for example, if you were on $179$ and rolled, your expected value would be $\frac{0+181+182+183+184+185+186+187+188+189}{10}=166.5$, substantially less than the $179$ you could have by not rolling.
This may be why your simulated expected score at the start of $5.91$ looks too low, less than a third of that of the optimum strategy.
Here is some R code which generalises for all multiples and dice, three-quarters of which of which is messaging describing the optimal strategy.
expectedrollsum <- function(multiple, sides, strategy=TRUE){
  value <- 1:(multiple*sides)
  value[(1:sides) * multiple] <- 0
  for (n in (sides*(multiple-1)):1){
    value[n] <- ifelse(n %% multiple == 0, 0, max(n, 
                       sum(value[n+(1:sides)])/sides))
    }
  if (strategy == TRUE){
    nonroll <- which(value <= 1:(sides*multiple))
    nonroll <- nonroll[nonroll %% multiple > 0] 
    roll <- which(value > 1:(sides*multiple))
    roll <- roll[roll %% multiple > multiple-sides-1]   
    print("Roll at the start")
    if(multiple > sides + 1){
      print(paste("and at values", 1, "to", multiple-sides-1, 
                  "more than multiples of", multiple, collapse=" "))
      }
    if(nonroll[1] < max(roll)){
      print(paste("and at other values <=", max(roll), "except", 
                   paste(nonroll[nonroll < max(roll)], collapse=","),
                   collapse=" "))
      }else{
      print(paste("and at other values <=", max(roll), collapse=" "))
      }
    print(paste("Expected value at start:", 
                sum(value[1:sides])/sides, collapse=" "))
    }
  return(sum(value[1:sides])/sides)
  }

which gives, for your question with multiples of $10$ and $10$-sided dice, an expected gain of about $19.5$:
expectedrollsum(multiple=10, sides=10, strategy=TRUE)
# "Roll at the start"
# "and at other values <= 49"
# "Expected value at start: 19.4988157426995"

confirming user2661923's strategy of "roll if and only if your current winnings are  $\le 49$".
The same code also reproduces Matthew M. Conroy's results for $6$-sided dice on page 111 of his A Collection of Dice Problems such as
expectedrollsum(multiple=6,  sides=6,  strategy=TRUE)
# "Roll at the start"
# "and at other values <= 17"
# "Expected value at start: 7.22145162310829"

expectedrollsum(multiple=10, sides=6,  strategy=TRUE)
# "Roll at the start"
# "and at values 1 to 3 more than multiples of 10"
# "and at other values <= 29 except 24,25"
# "Expected value at start: 13.2171185904247"
 
expectedrollsum(multiple=20, sides=6,  strategy=TRUE)
# "Roll at the start"
# "and at values 1 to 13 more than multiples of 20"
# "and at other values <= 79 except 54,55,56,74,75,76,77,78"
# "Expected value at start: 28.7591295525254"


This answer does not assume a priori that an optimal strategy exists, nor that an optimal strategy must be of any particular form (such as "roll again if your score is less than a certain value $N$, otherwise stop").  Indeed, there is an optimal strategy, and it is of this form, and we prove these statements below.

Let's call your game $G$, and let's also consider a different game, called $G2$.  In $G2$, just like in $G$, at all times your current score is a non-negative integer.  And, whenever you have a score $n=10a+b$, where $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $b\in\{0, 1, \ldots, 9\}$, you are allowed to either:
(a) Stop, and the game ends, and you finish with a score of $n$.
Or:
(b) Roll a fair $10$-sided die with face values $\{1, 2, \ldots, 10\}$, and let $r$ be the result of your die roll.  If $n+r\equiv 0\pmod{10}$ (that is, if $r = 10-b$), then the game ends.  BUT: in $G2$, if this happens you are allowed to keep your current score of $n$; you don't go back to $0$.  And on the other hand if $r\neq 10-b$, then you add $r$ to your current score and you get the same choices again.
It should be clear that your scores will be higher in $G2$ than in $G$.  We will make this precise in Theorem 1 below; first we need some preliminaries.
Definition: Choose any strategy $U$ for the game $G$. (This $U$ may be an "optimal" strategy, but doesn't have to be.)  With the choice of $U$ being fixed from now on, let $E_{G}(n)$ be your expected final score in game $G$, assuming your current score is $n$.
Meanwhile, let $E_{G2}(n)$ be your expected final score in game $G2$, assuming optimal play and assuming your current score is $n$.  Notice that we do assume an optimal strategy in  $G2$...but in $G2$ the optimal strategy is obvious: keep rolling as long as you can, because you can only ever increase your expectation by rolling again.  (There is no "risk" in game $G2$. In game $G2$, the "always roll again" strategy is strictly better than any strategy in which we have a chance of stopping before we are forced to.)
Fact: Given any $n=10a+b$, where $a$ is a nonnegative integer and $b\in \{0, 1, \ldots, 9\}$,
$$
E_G(n) \leq \max\left(n, \frac{1}{10}\sum_{r\in \{1, 2, \ldots, 10  \} \setminus \{10-b  \} } E_G(n+r) \right).
$$
(If the strategy is optimal then the inequality above will be replaced by an equality. But optimal or not, there are only ever two choices, and they lead to the two possible formulas shown above.  So we can't do better than the better of the two.)
Theorem 1: For every nonnegative integer $n$,
$$
E_{G}(n)\leq E_{G2}(n).
$$
Proof: Choose any strategy $U$ for game $G$; then $U$ is also a legal strategy in $G2$.  Regardless of what sequence of rolls you get, your ending score in $G2$ is guaranteed to be at least as high, as your ending score in $G$ (assuming the same sequence of rolls in both games, and assuming the same starting value and same strategy in both games).  Therefore the expectation in game $G2$ is at least as high as the expectation in game $G$.  Of course, the optimal strategy in $G2$ will if anything give even a higher expected value (by definition). $\Box$
So $E_{G2}(n)$ is always an upper bound for $E_G(n)$.  And in turn, we can calculate an explicit upper bound for $E_{G2}(n)$:
$$
\begin{align*}
E_{G2}(n) &\leq n + \frac{1}{10}(0) + \left(\frac{9}{10}\right) \frac{1}{10} (10) + \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^2 \frac{1}{10} (20) + \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^3 \frac{1}{10} (30) +\cdots\\
&= n + \left(\frac{9}{10}\right) (1) + \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^2 (2) + \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^3 (3) +\cdots\\
&= n + f\left( \frac{9}{10} \right),
\end{align*}
$$
where
$$
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^k \\
&= x \sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1} \\
&= x\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} x^k\\
&= x \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k\\
&= x \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x} - 1\right)\\
&= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.
\end{align*}
$$
Therefore
$$
E_{G2}(n) \leq n + \frac{9/10}{1/100} = n + 90.
$$
This upper bound on $E_{G2}(n)$ comes from essentially replacing each of our rolls with a better roll (of $10$).  More precisely, we create a new game $G3$, where the rules are the same as in $G2$, except that in $G3$ we keep track of two numbers: the "game state score" $n$, which is the same as the $n$ we had before, and which determines whether the game continues; and also a separate "outcome score" $N$, which is calculated by adding $10$ for each time you roll successfully (meaning that the game keeps going).  Clearly $n\leq N$ always (by induction).  In $G3$, when the game ends our final score is $N$, rather than $n$.  The optimal strategy is the same in $G2$ and $G3$, but the scores are always (if anything) higher in $G3$ than in $G2$.  In $G3$, the expected final score, given a current score of $n$ and assuming optimal play, is $n+90$.
Putting our results together, for each $n$ we have:
$$
\begin{align*}
E_G(n) &\leq \max\left(n, \frac{1}{10}\sum_{r\in \{1, 2, \ldots, 10  \} \setminus \{10-b  \} } E_G(n+r) \right)\\
&\leq \max\left(n, \frac{1}{10}\sum_{r\in \{1, 2, \ldots, 10  \} \setminus \{10-b  \} } E_{G2}(n+r) \right)\\
&\leq \max\left(n, \frac{1}{10}\sum_{r\in \{1, 2, \ldots, 10  \} \setminus \{10-b  \} } (n+r+90) \right)\\
&\leq \max\left(n, \frac{1}{10}\sum_{r\in \{2, 3, \ldots, 10  \}  } (n+r+90) \right)\\
&= \max\left(n, \frac{9}{10}(n+90) + \frac{1}{10}\sum_{r=2}^{10} r \right)\\
&= \max\left(n, \frac{9}{10}(n) +\frac{864}{10} \right).
\end{align*}
$$
Theorem 2: In game $G$, for all $n\geq 864$, if your current score is $n$ then you are better off to stop than to roll again.
Proof: If $n\geq 864$ then
$$
n \geq \frac{9}{10}n + \frac{864}{10},
$$
so regardless of your chosen strategy,
$$
E_G(n) \leq \max\left(n, \frac{9}{10}n + \frac{864}{10}\right) = n.
$$
Therefore with a score of $n$, it is impossible to do better than to achieve an expectation of $n$, which is exactly what we get if we stop. $\Box$
Finally, we can use this information to determine the best choices at all $n<864$ as well.  Of course we choose "stop" for all $n\geq 864$.  Then, starting at $n=863$ and counting downward, we always choose our strategy so that
$$
E_G(n) = \max\left( n, \frac{1}{10}\sum_{r\in \{1, 2, \ldots, 10  \} \setminus \{10-b  \} } E_G(n+r)  \right).
$$
If $n$ is equal to this maximum, then it means we should stop with a score of $n$; if not, it means we should roll again with a score of $n$. This is the best we can do; in other words, it is the optimal choice.
Write $E_n$ to mean $E_G(n)$, assuming optimal strategy; in particular we know that $E_n = n$ for all $n \in \{864, 865, 866, \ldots\} \setminus\{10, 20, 30, 40\ldots\}$, and we also have $E_n=0$ for all $n\in\{10,20,30,40,\ldots\}$.  Also let $R_n = \frac{1}{10}\sum_{r\in \{1, 2, \ldots, 10  \}  } E_{n+r}$. Now
$$
\begin{align*}
E_{863} &= \max\left(863, \frac{1}{10}(864+865 + \cdots + 869+871+872+873)\right) = \max(863,781.5) = 863\\
E_{862} &= \max\left(862, \frac{1}{10}(863 + 864 + \cdots + 869+ 871 +872)\right) = \max(862,780.5) = 862
\\
E_{861} &= \max\left(861, \frac{1}{10}(862 + 863 + \cdots + 869+ 871 )\right) = \max(861,779.5) = 861\\
E_{860} &= 0\\
E_{859} &= \max\left(859, \frac{1}{10}(861 + 862 + 863 + \cdots + 869)\right) = \max(859,778.5) = 859
\end{align*}
$$
We notice that each time the $n$-value decreases by $1$, so does the $R_n$ value...except that when $n$ goes from $10a+11$ down to $10a+9$, the value of $n$ decreases by $2$ but $R_n$ decreases by only $1$.  So eventually $R_n$ will no longer be less than $n$.  In fact, at $n=859$ we have $n-R_n = 80.5$, which means that if we decrease the tens place of $n$ by $81$ (in other words, set $n=859-81\cdot 10$), then $R_n$ should be greater than $n$.  And indeed,
$$
E_{49} = \max(49, \frac{1}{10}(51 + \cdots + 59)) = \max(49,49.5) = 49.5.
$$
Next we will have
$$
E_{48} = \max(48, \frac{1}{10}(49.5 + 51 + 52 + 53 +  \cdots + 58)) = 48.55
$$
$$
E_{47} = \max(47, \frac{1}{10}(48.55 + 49.5 + 51 + 52 + 53 +  \cdots + 57)) = 47.605
$$
etc.
In particular, we find that in game $G$ we should reroll if and only if $n < 50$, and
$$
\begin{align*}
E_0 &= \frac{38997631485399018686004041889814171465440139451}{2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000}\\
\\
&= 19.4988157426995093430020209449070857327200697255.
\end{align*}
$$

Postscript: There are some games which do not admit an optimal strategy. For an example of such a game: start with a score of $1$. On your turn you have the choice to stop the game, in which case you finish with your current score, or you can flip a coin. If you flip a Tails, then you lose everything and the game ends, but if you flip a Heads then you triple your score and you get another turn. In this game, any strategy in which you stop after $M$ turns, is worse than a strategy in which you stop after $M+1$ turns. But a strategy in which you never stop is the worst of all, because it guarantees that you don't win anything.

On each turn, your expected gain is avg(1..10)=5.5, and, because there's a 10% chance of losing everything, your expected loss is total/10 - so you should stop at 55: above this, your expected loss is greater than your expected gain.
Can't think why everyone else wrote so much! :)

But the "expected gain" is never $5.5$. Rolling at $51$ is a losing bet, because you have only a $0.9$ chance to win, and if you do win you can only expect to win the average of the numbers $1$ through $8$ and $10$, which is about $5.111$; a $9$ is a loss. And $0.9\cdot5.111-01\cdot51<0$.

People had to write so much because the simple answer is wrong, although it's at least in the right ballpark -- as pointed out here.
